# How to Center your Foundation Nav bar/ Top-bar

Tags: html, css, center, zurb-foundation, nav

There are loads of posts about this asking for an answer, most are half right or just don't work.

You can use the example nav-bar and add acouple of edits which will be in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply copy and paste the Foundation top-bar example from [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html).
Put this in your HTML,

1. Delete the left or right section of the top-bar
2. Delete left and right from the `<ul class="left">' or '<ul class="right">`
3. Delete `<h1><a href="#">Top Bar Title </a></h1>` from the title section.
4. Add

   ```
   .top-bar-section ul {display: table; margin: 0 auto;}

   .top-bar-section ul li {display: table-cell;}
   ```

in
 `@media only screen and (min-width: 58.75em) {`
Just before the `}` closing tag.

This should now leave you with 3 buttons if you chose the left side and it should be perfectly centered

Comment: This will cause you to lose functionality when it goes to the mobile version of the top-bar, please see my answer below

Comment: I have not lost any functionality from this, I have it running on 3 sites and its been tested on multiple browsers and devices. That being said, you need to tailor it for the sizes in general you come across.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I've found that works for all resize events. It centers the Foundation 5 Top-bar elements.

Do note the 'contain-to-grid' div class will keep the widths of the top-bar nav within the frameworks of the website yet will not actually center the nav elements.

The code below does.

SCSS:

```
nav.top-bar:not(.expanded) {
            text-align: center;
            section.top-bar-section { display: inline-block; }
                           }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contain-to-grid">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="#"></a></h1>
            </li>
            <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul>
                <li><%= link_to 'LINK 1', root_path %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to 'LINK2', link_path %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <%= link_to 'Dropping', "#" %>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><label>Label:</label></li>
                        <li><%= link_to 'DROP 1', drop_path %></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><%= link_to 'DROP 2', drop_path %></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```